# use DOMParser or SAXParser from Nekohtml in android project

Tags: android

I try to use nekohtml to parse html file.

Problem: When i use DOMParser or SAXParser, i receive these messages:

```
  In my console:
```

trouble processing:
 Dx bad utf-8 byte 80 at offset 00000021
...while parsing cst 0213 at offset 00001732
...while parsing cst 0053 at offset 00000176
...while parsing org/apache/xerces/impl/xpath/regex/Token.class
...while processing org/apache/xerces/impl/xpath/regex/Token.class
trouble processing:
[2012-03-07 18:50:32 - info] Dx bad utf-8 byte a0 at offset 00000004
...while parsing cst 00c0 at offset 00000909
...while parsing cst 003b at offset 00000106
...while parsing org/apache/xerces/impl/xpath/regex/ParserForXMLSchema.class
...while processing org/apache/xerces/impl/xpath/regex/ParserForXMLSchema.class

Dx warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class
(org.apache.xerces.impl.xpath.XPath$1) that doesn't come with an
associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a
compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended
solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler
and without specifying any "-target" type options. The consequence of ignoring
this warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly
indicate that it is not an inner class.

```
   In my LogCat window:
```

Could not find method org.apache.xerces.xni.NamespaceContext.declarePrefix, referenced from method org.cyberneko.html.xercesbridge.XercesBridge_2_3.NamespaceContext_declarePrefix

FY: unable to resolve interface method 5699: Lorg/apache/xerces/xni/NamespaceContext;. declarePrefix(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/Sring;)Z

Making a copy of Lorg/cyberneko/html/xercesbridge/XercesBridge_2_3;.NamespaceContext_declarePrefix code (24 bytes)

I don't put all the message because is long

Please, I want to know how I can fix this problem.. thanks